# Use a SKEmitterNode across multiple SKScenes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene, skemitternode

I have a new game I've just started building in sprite kit with swift and I'm wondering how I can use a SKEmitterNode seamlessly across multiple scenes. At the moment my game consists of 3 scenes: menu, game and game over. I want to use the SKEmitterNode in the background across all 3 scenes without any stops. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You will need to provide more info because what you are asking is way to generic.  You can't have 3 scenes on the screen at once, so I am going to have to assume you are transitioning to each scene.  What kind of transition are you using?  The simplest approach would be to move your `SKEmitter` to the new scene, and in the `SKTransition`,  make sure you enable animations on the new scene

Comment: @Knight0fDragon It looks to me that he just wants the same emitter running in the background in all of his scenes without reseting an actual simulation (emitting) ... So basically he wants an emitter which will survive transitions...

Comment: @Whirlwind, yeah that is what I am figuring, but I hate assuming.  I can't edit the comment now, but I mean move the actual SKEmitter node across the various scenes, not spawn a new one

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Yeah, I understood what you said about passing the emitter around. It make sense, but I wonder how changing a parent of an emitter will affect on existing simulation...

Comment: @Whirlwind yeah good question, guess jm1175 could give it a try and let us know

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try tomorrow and see how I go.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to KnightOfDragon and Whirlwind helping in the comments, simply passing the emitter to the next scene works fine and without interrupting the particles.

I set up the `SKEmitterNode` in a 'intro' scene and declared it globally.

Then on the current scene just before moving to the next:

```
emitter.removeFromParent()
```

and in the new scene:

```
addChild(emitter)
```